# RecyclerView and ArrayList - How to add a user image from database?

Tags: android

I currently have RecyclerView + ArrayList of Strings. The strings represent user ids. Each user id has a profile picture. My adapter has an ImageView and a TextView. Currently the TextView displays the user id for each user, but the ImageView holds a default image for all users. How to add the ability to fetch the image of the user profile picture according to his id. Do I need to change the ArrayList to hold other type of data? Or it's possible to leave it as String with the user id, and for each user id fetch the image on the go?
Also, if I change the ArrayList data from String to something else, what do I need to change in the adapter?
This is the code:

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView singleItemTextView;
    public ImageView singleItemImage;
    public View layout;
    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        singleItemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        singleItemTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userId);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                 int viewType) {


    View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.user_profile_list, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.singleItemTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your `onBindViewHolder`, right after the `holder.singleItemTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));`

Just make sure you fetch the image asynchronously.

Comment: So I do not need to create a `User` class right? I can leave it to be with Strings array

Comment: Yes. Ideally though, it would be nice for you to fetch all the data from the DB asynchronously before setting the adapter to the RecyclerView and then load an array of Users into your Adapter. If you do that, you only query your database once for all the images but if you do it on the onBindViewHolder, you will query the DB every time the RecyclerView want's to draw that item.